# How to check the number of string of an input number?

Tags: matlab

For instance I have an input of 3.142 what command could I use to determine the number of string the numbers. In this case I wish to get something like 5 included the decimal points. More eg like,

> 12.3 then will get an output of 4
>
> 12.345 will will get an output of 6

Comment: lookup the following functions: `size`, `length`, `numel`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `length` function.

```
myNumberString = '12.3456';
disp(length(myNumberString));
```

In the above code, you should get `7` displayed in your command window when you run it.

Comment: You might additionally find `num2str` helpful: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html